# what will be regular expression for email with custom domain in parsley validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, email, parsley

I have a form on which I want to apply parsley validation. I want to allow only email with domain `@ciit-atk.edu.pk` but I don't have a regex for it that will work with parsley validation. The sample email is `xx-xx-xx@ciit-atk.edu.pk` and any other email not having the same domain will not be accepted. I don't want a generic regex, I need a regex for this specific domain that will work with parsley validation.

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email..." required data-parsley-pattern="" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" >
```

The regex will go in `data-parsley-pattern` field. I have this regex `"^[\w-\._\+%]+@(ciit-atk.edu.pk)"` but it's not working.

Comment: Can't you just check that the end matches, something like `"@ciit-atk\.edu\.pk$"`? Or are there more conditions, like check for only a single `@` etc.?

Comment: I only have to check the end but @ must be there.

Comment: but trying the "@ciit-atk\.edu\.pk$" still submits the form if I dont use the given the domain and use @gmail instead to submit the form

Comment: I would almost assume that this is an issue with the library/configuration. All the regexes should work. To debug this, you could try some really simple ones (like existence of a digit) to check whether the parsley library is even using the provided regex or just ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let emailTrue = 'xx-xx-xx@ciit-atk.edu.pk';
let emailFalse = 'asd@gmail.com';

let emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(ciit-atk.edu.pk)$/;
    
console.log(emailRegex.test(emailTrue));
console.log(emailRegex.test(emailFalse));
```

Comment: Sir I dont want to use the complete javascript code and only want to use the parsley library of jquery. I only need the regex explained in the question and unfortunately the regex you used in above code still sbmits the form if I enters wrong email